# How can I define a nonstandard file counterpart in Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode, ide, header, header-files

I have some files which are structured (something) like this:

```
MONLibrary/file.h
MONLibrary/file.support.h
```

I'd like Xcode to recognize these files as counterparts of each other, much like `file.h` and `file.c` are recognized counterparts. How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly what you're after (I'd like to know if there's an answer to that too...), but renaming `file.support.h` to `file.support` will cause it to be recognized as a counterpart.

It won't be treated as an Obj-C header file by default w/r/t syntax highlighting/build rules, but you can easily override this with the file inspector (⌘-opt-1).